# Drupal 7 new field added to content type doesn't appear

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type called Program . Now i have added a new field (type is Long text)to this content type. Then created a new content of this type and added some text in this field and saved . But my program page doesn't display this field. I am using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Try to change options in "manage display" in the content type.
Also you could try to change the input format (maybe what you have entered is filtered by that).
Make sure the background and the foreground are in different color (it may sound stupid but sometimes the more stupid is the error the more time is spent).

If nothing of this works... make sure you are using the default templates.